# dojo with phonegap for android

Tags: android, dojo, cordova

I want use dojo in phonegap application.I tried test applications of dojo in android.But they are not displaying anything in emulator.Can anyone help me how to use dojo in phonegap application.

thanks
Himabindu

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Have you tried the dojox.mobile demo page in the Dojo web site?  You should have a working site before you use PhoneGap to compile it.

Comment: yes i tried them..I created one dynamic web project and I tested the tweetview applocation.It is working fine.But i want the same application to run in emulator.For that i created android project.As the phonegap framework allows html code run in android, i copied dojo into www folder of the project and used tweetview.html.I don't know whether it is correct or not.It is not displaying anything in emulator.

Comment: I believe the mobile stuff are under the dojox/... tree.  Have you copied the dojox tree?

Answer (score 2):

Android has some problems with the dynamic loading. This means you have to make a custom-build of dojo 1.7.1.

To make a custom build you need the [src version of dojo](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/).

I extended the profile file "baseplus.profile.js" found in the directory "dojo/util/builsscripts/profiles/" as follows:

```
dependencies = {
    selectorEngine: "acme",
    layers: [
             {
// This is a specially named layer, literally 'dojo.js'
// adding dependencies to this layer will include the modules    
// in addition to the standard dojo.js base APIs.    
             name: "dojo.js",    
             dependencies: [    
                 "dijit._Widget",    
                 "dijit._Templated",    
                 "dojo.fx",    
                 "dojo.NodeList-fx",    
//this wasn't included in the standard build but necessary 
                 "dojo._firebug.firebug",    
 //my used dojo requirements
                 "dojox.mobile.parser",    
                 "dojox.mobile",     
                 "dojox.mobile.Button",    
                 "dojox.mobile.SwapView",    
                 "dojox.mobile.ScrollableView",    
                 "dojox.mobile.TabBar",     
                 "dojox.mobile.SpinWheelTimePicker",     
                 "dojox.mobile.compat"    
            ]     
       }    
], 

prefixes: [   
       ["dijit", "../dijit" ],    
       ["dojox", "../dojox" ]    
]    
}
```

you have to execute the build.sh (Unix/OSx) or build.bat (Windows) in the shell with the command "./build.sh action=release profile=profiles/myBaseplus.profile.js -r"

After a successful build you find the dojo.js file in "dojo/release/djojo/dojo.js".

You only need this file.

Never the less you will also need the following require statement in your html file:

```
require([    
                     "dojox/mobile/parser",      // (Optional) This mobile app uses declarative programming with fast mobile parser    
                     "dojox/mobile",             // (Required) This is a mobile app.    
                     "dojox/mobile/Button",    
                     "dojox/mobile/SwapView",    
                     "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",    
                     "dojox/mobile/TabBar",    
                     "dojox/mobile/SpinWheelTimePicker",    
                     "dojox/mobile/compat"       // (Optional) This mobile app supports running on desktop browsers    
                     ],
                     function(parser, mobile, compat){    
                    //Optional module aliases that can then be referenced inside callback block    
                    }    
 );
```

Comment: specifically, this [android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5343)

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming tweetview.html to index.html.

The PhoneGap entry point file name needs to match the file name from the native source. On Android the connection comes from src/{com.package}/{activityname}.java.

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```